# Does this mean to exclude holiday, jury duty, illness, personal time or vacation from the absence?

Tags: meaning

Was employee absent from work for reasons other than Work Sharing, including a holiday, jury duty, illness, personal leave, or vacation during this week?

Comment: The clause starting *including* applies either to 'Work Sharing' or to 'reasons other than Work Sharing'; which do you think more likely?

Comment: I guess it depends on what 'Work Sharing' is and whether it would reasonably include all those things. Presumably not. Thus it is likely that those items are meant to be a fairly comprehensive list of reasons one might be absent aside from 'Work Sharing'... and not included in it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm familiar with Work Sharing, and it isn't related to the listed reasons. That means that "including" refers to "reasons other than Work Sharing," so the sentence is asking whether the employee was absent for *any* reason *other than* Work Sharing.